# Can my closed question be rephrased or it won't fit here at all?

Tags: discussion

Please help me rephrase my [closed question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17015/platform-or-community-for-solving-visualisation-rebus), I believe there must be a place for it on this great forum. I am not advertising my project or anything like that, I am really looking for help.

Also I think it totally fits the [UX field](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/ux-field/info) tag, doesn't it?

Should I maybe directly ask a question about the complex problem I mention? Even though it could be long :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking the actual question would be a step up from asking a Q&A community where you can go to ask questions, yes. ;)

Comment: my only worry is that the problem is too complex. But I will try it.